# Mongo db read on big collection

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, etl

I have an ETL process that needs to pull data from a very large Mongo collection (150 million documents).  I was originally using Spring data's template like this:

```
this.template.find(this.mongoQuery.limit(this.pageSize).skip(this.pageSize * this.currentPage++), MyModel.class, this.collection);
```

This worked fine when I was running the ETL against 17 million documents in my dev environment (20 secs every 100K documents -- pageSize), but after 11.5 million records it will go from 20sec to 4 mins to retrieved the next pages. Also, this didn't scale at all to 160 Million documents live.

One of the main problems that I have is that I don't control the way the mongo collection is structure and my filter criteria is based on a date range on several attributes date attributes in the documents, and these dates are not indexed since the clients that use this collection don't filter by those dates, only my ETL.

I changed my implementation to use just use the java Mongo driver and set the batchSize to 500K which seemed to perform better, I didn't reach that slowdown after 11.5 million on my dev environment. So, my code became

```
cursor = this.template.getCollection(collection).find(mongoQuery.getQueryObject());
cursor.batchSize(pageSize);
//batch logic
List<MyModel> models = new ArrayList<MyModel>();
    for (DBObject result : cursor) {
        models.add(this.template.getConverter().read(MyModel.class, result));
        counter++;
        if (counter >= this.pageSize) {
            break;
        }
    }
    this.currentPage++;

    return models;
```

I haven't released this change live, so I don't know how well it will perform. What would be the best way to collect the documents that I am interested using a criteria where the attributes are not indexed on this very large collection? The only other idea, if this doesn't work, is to not pass a criteria and get all the documents, iterate over the 150 million documents in my ETL and do the filtering there.

Comment: I think that problem with the first implementation is how you use `skip`. If I am right right it iterates over `this.pageSize * this.currentPage` documents every time before it get's ti actual data and it is clearly inefficient. Using some already indexed field to obtain natural ranges could be a better solution. About second one - in both cases you'll end up with reading every document so it it probably better to at least avoid network overhead and leave filtering to mongod.